# Error when executing java -jar in spring boot app but not compiling

Tags: spring-boot, jar, resources, postconstruct

When I compile the application it works perfect, also test are passed but then if I execute java -jat in the compiled jar i had the following error when trying to load a jpg resource:

```
XXX@XXXX MINGW64 /d/Proyectos/PetApp/Back (master)
$ mvn clean install

###########################################################
__________        __    __     _____ ____________________
\______   \ _____/  |__/  |_  /  _  \\______   \______   \
 |     ___// __ \   __\   __\/  /_\  \|     ___/|     ___/
 |    |   \  ___/|  |  |  | /    |    \    |    |    |
 |____|    \___  >__|  |__| \____|__  /____|    |____|
               \/                   \/
###########################################################

2019-10-16 15:29:59,977 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger: Starting BackEndTestApplicationTests on gggarrido10 with PID 4436 (started by gggarrido in D:\Proyectos\PetApp\Back)
2019-10-16 15:29:59,980 DEBUG [main] org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger: Running with Spring Boot v2.1.6.RELEASE, Spring v5.1.8.RELEASE
2019-10-16 15:29:59,981 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication: No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-10-16 15:30:04,187 INFO  [main] com.mashosoft.backEndTest.config.DDBB.DDBBConfig: H2 DDBB selected
2019-10-16 15:30:08,767 INFO  [main] com.mashosoft.backEndTest.config.DDBB.DDBBInitializer: Initializacion of the DDBB
2019-10-16 15:30:09,002 INFO  [main] com.mashosoft.backEndTest.config.DDBB.DDBBInitializer: Role: ADMIN stored on DDBB
2019-10-16 15:30:09,006 INFO  [main] com.mashosoft.backEndTest.config.DDBB.DDBBInitializer: Role: USER stored on DDBB
2019-10-16 15:30:09,017 INFO  [main] com.mashosoft.backEndTest.config.DDBB.DDBBInitializer: Role: VISITOR stored on DDBB
2019-10-16 15:30:09,237 INFO  [main] com.mashosoft.backEndTest.config.DDBB.DDBBInitializer: Default AdminUser Created: AdminRoot/AdminPass246
2019-10-16 15:30:09,237 INFO  [main] com.mashosoft.backEndTest.config.DDBB.DDBBInitializer: Default Owner Created: Manolo Amelgas
2019-10-16 15:30:09,253 INFO  [main] com.mashosoft.backEndTest.config.DDBB.DDBBInitializer: Default Pet Created: Lucky
2019-10-16 15:30:14,019 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger: Started BackEndTestApplicationTests in 14.867 seconds (JVM running for 16.865)
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 16.279 s - in com.mashosoft.backEndTest.BackEndTestApplicationTests
[INFO] Running com.mashosoft.backEndTest.security.service.Impl.AuthServiceImplTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 s - in com.mashosoft.backEndTest.security.service.Impl.AuthServiceImplTest
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.1.2:jar (default-jar) @ pettapp ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\Proyectos\PetApp\Back\target\pettapp-V.RELEASE.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.8.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) @ pettapp ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ pettapp ---
[INFO] Installing D:\Proyectos\PetApp\Back\target\pettapp-V.RELEASE.jar to D:\Tools\.m2\repository\com\mashosoft\pettapp\V.RELEASE\pettapp-V.RELEASE.jar
[INFO] Installing D:\Proyectos\PetApp\Back\pom.xml to D:\Tools\.m2\repository\com\mashosoft\pettapp\V.RELEASE\pettapp-V.RELEASE.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 34.801 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-16T15:30:18+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 49M/331M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

XXX@XXXX MINGW64 /d/Proyectos/PetApp/Back (master)
$ cd target/

XXX@XXX MINGW64 /d/Proyectos/PetApp/Back/target (master)
$ java -jar pettapp-V.RELEASE.jar



###########################################################
__________        __    __     _____ ____________________
\______   \ _____/  |__/  |_  /  _  \\______   \______   \
 |     ___// __ \   __\   __\/  /_\  \|     ___/|     ___/
 |    |   \  ___/|  |  |  | /    |    \    |    |    |
 |____|    \___  >__|  |__| \____|__  /____|    |____|
               \/                   \/
###########################################################

2019-10-16 15:30:33,466 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger: Starting BackEndTestApplication vV.RELEASE on gggarrido10 with PID 11360 (D:\Proyectos\PetApp\Back\target\pettapp-V.RELEASE.jar started by gggarrido in D:\Proyectos\PetApp\Back\target)
2019-10-16 15:30:33,472 DEBUG [main] org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger: Running with Spring Boot v2.1.6.RELEASE, Spring v5.1.8.RELEASE
2019-10-16 15:30:33,475 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication: No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-10-16 15:30:37,905 INFO  [main] com.mashosoft.backEndTest.config.DDBB.DDBBConfig: H2 DDBB selected
2019-10-16 15:30:41,331 INFO  [main] com.mashosoft.backEndTest.config.DDBB.DDBBInitializer: Initializacion of the DDBB
2019-10-16 15:30:41,792 INFO  [main] com.mashosoft.backEndTest.config.DDBB.DDBBInitializer: Role: ADMIN stored on DDBB
2019-10-16 15:30:41,795 INFO  [main] com.mashosoft.backEndTest.config.DDBB.DDBBInitializer: Role: USER stored on DDBB
2019-10-16 15:30:41,800 INFO  [main] com.mashosoft.backEndTest.config.DDBB.DDBBInitializer: Role: VISITOR stored on DDBB
2019-10-16 15:30:41,918 INFO  [main] com.mashosoft.backEndTest.config.DDBB.DDBBInitializer: Default AdminUser Created: AdminRoot/AdminPass246
2019-10-16 15:30:41,919 INFO  [main] com.mashosoft.backEndTest.config.DDBB.DDBBInitializer: Default Owner Created: Manolo Amelgas
2019-10-16 15:30:41,963 ERROR [main] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DDBBInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mashosoft.backEndTest.exception.initialization.InitializationException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:139)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:414)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202)
        at com.mashosoft.backEndTest.BackEndTestApplication.main(BackEndTestApplication.java:18)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
Caused by: com.mashosoft.backEndTest.exception.initialization.InitializationException: null
        at com.mashosoft.backEndTest.config.DDBB.DDBBInitializer.getTestPetImageAsMultipart(DDBBInitializer.java:123)
        at com.mashosoft.backEndTest.config.DDBB.DDBBInitializer.init(DDBBInitializer.java:100)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
        ... 26 common frames omitted
```

This is the class:

```
package com.mashosoft.backEndTest.config.DDBB;

import com.mashosoft.backEndTest.component.ImageUploader;
import com.mashosoft.backEndTest.exception.errorcode.InitializationErrorCodes;
import com.mashosoft.backEndTest.exception.initialization.InitializationException;
import com.mashosoft.backEndTest.persistence.entity.Owner;
import com.mashosoft.backEndTest.persistence.entity.Pet;
import com.mashosoft.backEndTest.persistence.repository.OwnerRepository;
import com.mashosoft.backEndTest.persistence.repository.PetRepository;
import com.mashosoft.backEndTest.security.model.enums.Roles;
import com.mashosoft.backEndTest.security.persistence.entity.Role;
import com.mashosoft.backEndTest.security.persistence.entity.User;
import com.mashosoft.backEndTest.security.persistence.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.mashosoft.backEndTest.security.persistence.repository.UserRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

@Configuration
public class DDBBInitializer {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( DDBBInitializer.class );

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private OwnerRepository ownerRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PetRepository petRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Value("${pettapp.config.default.username}")
    private String defaultUsername;

    @Value("${pettapp.config.default.email}")
    private String defaultEmail;

    @Value("${pettapp.config.default.password}")
    private String defaultPassword;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {

        log.info( "Initializacion of the DDBB" );

        for (Roles role : Roles.values()) {
            Role roleEntity = new Role( role );
            roleRepository.save( roleEntity );
            log.info( "Role: " + roleEntity.getRoleName() + " stored on DDBB" );
        }

        User defaultAdminUser = new User();
        defaultAdminUser.setUserId( new BigDecimal( 1 ) );
        defaultAdminUser.addOneRole( Roles.ADMIN );
        defaultAdminUser.setUsername( defaultUsername );
        defaultAdminUser.setPassword( passwordEncoder.encode( defaultPassword ) );
        defaultAdminUser.setActive( true );
        defaultAdminUser.setEmail( defaultEmail );

        log.info( "Default AdminUser Created: " + defaultAdminUser.getUsername() + "/" + defaultPassword );

        Owner adminOwnerProfile = new Owner();
        adminOwnerProfile.setAddress( "Calle de jacinto Nº6 Bajo B" );
        adminOwnerProfile.setName( "Manolo" );
        adminOwnerProfile.setSurname( "Amelgas" );
        adminOwnerProfile.setDefaulter( false );
        adminOwnerProfile.setTelephoneNumber( "678987656 " );
        adminOwnerProfile.setUser( defaultAdminUser );

        defaultAdminUser.setOwner( adminOwnerProfile );

        log.info( "Default Owner Created: " + adminOwnerProfile.getName() + " " + adminOwnerProfile.getSurname() );

        Pet testPet = new Pet();
        testPet.setAlive( true );
        testPet.setBitrh( new Date() );
        testPet.setBreed( "Carlino" );
        testPet.setFur( "White" );
        testPet.setName( "Lucky" );
        String imageUrl = ImageUploader.uploadFile( getTestPetImageAsMultipart() );
        testPet.setPictureUrl( imageUrl );
        testPet.setOwner( adminOwnerProfile );

        adminOwnerProfile.addPet( testPet );

        log.info( "Default Pet Created: " + testPet.getName() );

        userRepository.save( defaultAdminUser );

    }

    private MultipartFile getTestPetImageAsMultipart() {
        try {
            File file;
            try {
                file = new ClassPathResource( "/TestResources/DogImageForTest.jpg" ).getFile();
            } catch (IOException e){
                throw new InitializationException( InitializationErrorCodes.IMAGE_TEST_NOT_FOUND );
            }
            return new MockMultipartFile( "DogImageForTest.jpg", "DogImageForTest.jpg", "image/jpeg",
                new FileInputStream( file ) );
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            throw new InitializationException( InitializationErrorCodes.IMAGE_TEST_ERROR );
        }
    }
}
```

Why everything works fine but not when executing java -jar??
I dont know what to try because also in intellij when i press play or debug it works perfect.

The line that I know it is failing is the following:

file = new ClassPathResource( "/TestResources/DogImageForTest.jpg" ).getFile();

I have check inside the jar file and the image is inside:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Within a jar I cant use .getFile(); because it expect to have a file withint the system. Intead I used:

```
fileStream = new ClassPathResource( "/TestResources/DogImageForTest.jpg" ).getInputStream();
            return new MockMultipartFile( "DogImageForTest.jpg", "DogImageForTest.jpg", "image/jpeg",fileStream );
```

With a stream it works perfect

Comment: Hard coding is bad practice always try to make things configurable

Comment: I know, it was just a test but thanks for the advice! :)